# Compiling Berkeley DB with --enable-java and jvm 1.8.0

Tags: jvm, berkeley-db

For everyone’s information, I was getting compile errors when trying to compile the latest Berkeley DB (--enable-java was an option) with the latest jdk from oracle (JDK 1.8.0) and I was getting deprecation errors from "make".

I switched the jdk to open JDK 1.7.0 by setting the PATH variable to point to open JDK's bin (export PATH=*path to jdk/bin*:$PATH) and I was able to compile without errors.

Another way to fix the issue was to ignore deprecation error through -Xlint:deprecation, but I couldn't get it to work.

Jesse